# Configuring gunicorn for Django on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, gunicorn

I'm trying to setup a test Django project on Heroku.  Following the advice [here](http://blog.abhiomkar.in/2011/09/17/deploying-django-on-heroku-mac-os-x/) and in the [Heroku Getting Started](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python#declare_process_types_with_foremanprocfile) I'm trying to use `gunicorn` instead of the Django dev server.

This was my first attempt at the Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn_django --workers=4 --bind=0.0.0.0:$PORT my_project/settings.py
worker: python my_project/manage.py celeryd -E -B --loglevel=INFO
```

This gave me this error:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'settings.py' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named py
```

I decided to take a different track and followed the advice [here](http://v3.mike.tig.as/blog/2012/02/13/deploying-django-on-heroku/).  Now my Procfile looked like this:

```
web: gunicorn_django -b 0.0.0.0:\$PORT -w 9 -k gevent --max-requests 250 --preload my_project.settings
```

(I also updated my requirements file to include gevent.)  It gave me the same error:

```
ImportError: Could not import settings
```

Finally, I just set it to `settings`:

```
web: gunicorn_django -b 0.0.0.0:\$PORT -w 9 -k gevent --max-requests 250 --preload settings
```

But now I get this error:

```
Error: django project not found
```

The way my Django project is set up is that the `settings.py` file is in the parent directory of the repo -- I don't have the Django project under another directory.  It's at the same level as the virtualenv and git files.  Would that be a problem? I'm sure I'm doing something simple wrong -- any help would be much appreciated.

---

If I follow the instructions from Heroku [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django) and change the Procfile to this:

```
web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

Nothing happens -- no errors in the logs, but no proceses run and the app just appears dead in the water.

Comment: Have you seen the Heroku Quick Start article for Django specifically?  It includes detailed instructions for gunicorn.  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django

Comment: Yes, I have, and I'll add the details. Short answer -- nothing at all happens when I follow those directions.  The app just never starts.

Comment: Im having the same issue, basically went through all of these steps before finding this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have just run into this same issue. In the procfile you copied from the Heroku guide, change `hellodjango.wsgi` to `yourproject.wsgi`

Looks like we all fall victim to blindly copy-pasting now and then, but in your (and my) defense, it looks like there's no *.wsgi file that's actually being opened, it's just how you signal to gunicorn that you want it to run your django project.

Comment: You're actually specifying the Python module `yourproject/wsgi.py`.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same exact issue that you are having. The way I was able to finally get it working was to use the django app gunicorn.

I added gunicorn to the django settings.py

```
'gunicorn',
```

I then used this as my web entry in my Procfile.

```
web: python manage.py run_gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:\$PORT -w 9 -k gevent --max-requests 250 --preload
```

You may have to alter you .manage.py if you use a different directory structure then I did. My app was in /app, and my python path was also /app.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and landed up having to point directly to the python path and then set the settings [reference](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/322#issuecomment-5178494).

In the end my Procfile looks like this:

```
web: gunicorn_django --pythonpath=/app/project --settings=settings
```

I had to run `heroku run` which showed the env variables and that's where I was able to find the `/app` which I prepended to my project name.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `requirements.txt` in the root folder (containing the word `django`), as well as a `settings.py`?  Those appear to the be the requirements for Django app detection, as documented [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#django_applications).